# Getline issue with input of open file stream

Tags: c++, string, getline

I'm trying to figure out why this is broke now, because I had it working and I'm not sure what is wrong.  I'm trying a simple getline from a file that's been opened, however, the compiler keeps giving me errors.  I've tried finding someone else with these issues, but I haven't been able to find anyone else with this.  Any advice?

```
void Foo::bar(ifstream &inputFile)
{
// Read in the data, parse it out, and 
// call loadQueue
string input;
do {    
    getline(inputFile, input);
    loadQueue(input);
}while (!(inputFile.eof()));

}
```

Here is what I get in return:

```
g++    -c -o Airworthy.o Airworthy.cpp
Foo.cpp: In member function ‘void Airworthy::readData(std::ifstream&)’:
Foo.cpp:25:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&)’
Foo.cpp:25:27: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:55:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
```

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: In addition to what Andy said, you're likely to `loadQueue` being called for the last line of your file twice. Change your loop to `while (getline(inputFile, input)) { loadQueue(input); }`.

Comment: Please show us the entire error message. And to elaborate on sftrabbit, `eof()` doesn't return true when there's no more input, it only returns true *after* an input operation has already failed due to eof.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Or not.  The problem is that _until_ input has failed, `eof()` may or may not return `true`.  After having read the last line (or the last input, whatever it is), `eof()` may return either `true` or `false`; you can't really be sure which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to `#include` all the necessary standard headers. One possibility is:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Or perhaps you forgot to:

```
#include <string>
```

You always have to `#include` all pertinent standard headers explicitly, without relying on indirect inclusion through some other headers.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The declaration should be in `<string>` and that is already mentioned in the part of the diagnostic message he's shown us. You can't get `std::string` without getting the appropriate `getline` overload.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I tried not `#include`ing `<fstream>` and that is exactly the error I get.

Comment: Ahh, because it doesn't know `ifstream` is derived from `istream`. Alright, +1. But another fix would be to take an `istream &` parameter. Usually `fstream` parameters are a mistake.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Without including `<fstream>`, the compiler may not even know that there is a class `ifstream`.  But the correct solution is _not_ to include `<fstream>`; it is to use `istream` as the argument, not `ifstream`.

Comment: @Andy Prowl I have the #include <fstream> and <string>, so is there another possibility?

Comment: @johwiltb: Are you extra sure? I can't think of another possibility for *that* error.

Comment: @AndyProwl ahh I'm sorry.  I had it added to the header file, but not to implementation file.  I think it's more an issue with the Makefile, which is a whole other question itself, but adding '#include <fstream>' to the implementation file does make it work well

Answer (score 1):

As Andy says, you need the appropriate includes.  There are,
however, at least two other major problems with your code (one
of which will affect which includes you need):

- You should never (or almost never) pass `ifstream` as an
  argument to a function.  Unless the function is going to do an
  `open` or a `close`, you should pass it `std::istream&`, so that
  it can be called with any `istream`, and not just `ifstream`.

  Once you've changed this, you need to include `<istream>`, and
  not `<fstream>`.  (`<fstream>` includes `<istream>`.  And a lot
  more which you don't need.)
- You should never loop on `! inputFile.eof()`.  It doesn't
  work.  In your case, the loop should be

  ```
  while ( std::getline( inputFile, input ) ) {4
      //  ...
  }
  ```

  It works, and almost nothing else does.

  In general, a `do...while` loop is almost always wrong when
  doing input; it results in your processing the input even when
  it fails (which you do—any use of `input` after the
  `getline` but before testing whether the `getline` has succeeded
  is an error).  And the results of `inputFile.eof()` are not
  really well defined until input has failed.  Using
  `istream::eof()` to control a loop is almost always an error.

Comment: The function is called through the main application after the file is opened.  Following the function call, the file is then close.  But I will definitely work out the loop issue.  I appreciate the advice on that.

Comment: @johwiltb Regardless of when the function is called, if a function doesn't use any of the interface which is strictly `ifstream`, like `open` and `close`, then it should take an `istream&`, not an `ifstream&`.  In practice, it's very common for an application to start with an `ifstream`, only to switch to some custom, in house stream later; you don't want to have to find every function which reads from the stream, and change them.