# Do I have to use #include <string> beside <iostream>?

Tags: c++, string, types, include, iostream

I started learning C++ and I read a book which writes that I must use the `<string>` header file because the string type is not built directly into the compiler.
If I use the `<iostream>` I can use the string type.

Do I have to include the `<string>` header when I want to use the string type if I included the `<iostream>` header? Why? Is there some difference?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you have to include what you use. It's not mandated that standard headers include one another (with a few exceptions IIRC). It might work now, but might fail on a different compiler.

In your case, apparently `<iostream>` includes `<string>`, directly or indirectly, but don't rely on it.

Comment: It's probably a forward declaration of string (<ios> includes <iosfwd> which includes <stringfwd.h> ing gcc's implementation). I think that's standard behaviour (would have to check the standard though), so I believe he can rely on it when he doesn't need the full type.

Comment: @AnotherTest "I can use the string type" - tells me he needs the full type. If he doesn't, a forward-declaration would do, yes.

Comment: 27.5.1 states that <iostream> must include <iosfwd>. That only needs `char_traits`, so I'm not sure whether a compiler must also forward declare `string`. I still doubt that any implementation of iostream includes the entire string header.

Answer (score 10):

> Do I have to include the `<string>` header when I want to use the string type if I included the `<iostream>` header?

Yes, you have to. You cannot rely on relevant headers (e.g. `<string>`) being `#include`d indirectly through other headers (e.g. `<iostream>`), although this might be the case on some implementations.

And even when this may *seem* to work, it could lead to troubles if not all of the relevant overloads of some operators are imported, or if a class is forward-declared in a header you `#include`, but information on that class being derived from some other class is only contained in a header that does not get `#include`d.

See, for instance, [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264205/getline-issue-with-input-of-open-file-stream) for an example of such situations.

Comment: [ios_base::getloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc) returns a `std::locale` by value, and [locale::name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/name) returns `std::string` by value, so `#include <iostream>` is actually required to fully define `std::string`. Only the non-members from `<string>` are optional.

Comment: very good point. I just ran into an issue where some library code we are using relied on this and when we upgraded from a very old OS/compiler to a newer version, compilation broke for "no apparent reason" other than this.