# c++ cout and cin doesn't compiles

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to write a very basic c++ code using visual studio.
the code doesn't compile because of the 'cin' and 'cout'.
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class employer
{
private:
    string id;
    float work_hours, over_time_hours,hourly_salary,salary;
public:
    employer()
    {
        id="123456789";
        hourly_salary=25;
        work_hours=0;
        over_time_hours=0;
        salary=0;
    }
    void get_employer()
    {
        cin >> id >> salary >> work_hours >> over_time_hours;
    }
    void print_employer()
    {
        cout << "I.D. #" << id << "\n and his hourly salary is: " << salary << '\n';
    }
        void salary_calculation()
    {
        salary= (work_hours*hourly_salary + 1.5*over_time_hours*hourly_salary);
    }

};
int main(){
    employer employer1;
    employer1.get_employer();
    employer1.salary_calculation();
    employer1.print_employer();
    return 0;
}
```

and the compilation error is:

```
"1>ex1.cpp(21): error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
```

Comment: What is `string`? -- It should be `std::string`, which is used in `iostream`

Comment: @mike `using namespace std`

Comment: You need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce with GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VxCMwRqP5DJFi2y1) -- reproduced with VC2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506095/do-i-have-to-use-include-string-beside-iostream

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator>>` overloads for `string` are located in `string` header, so you should include it:

```
#include <string>
```