# C++ exception int catch block executes when string exception was thrown

Tags: c++, exception

I have been learning c++ recently and while working on exceptions, I came across something that confuses me. I threw a string exception and added multiple catch blocks to see how it works, and for some reason, the string exception is being caught in the **int catch block**. This is puzzling me and I cant see to find reasons why it would do it.

FYI, I am using **GCC v 5.3.0**

So, I was expecting the following message on the console.

```
String exception occurred: Something else went wrong
```

But instead, I got the following message.

```
Int exception occurred: 14947880
```

So I tried switching the order of the catch blocks and placed the string catch block on the top, and I got the string exception message. Could somebody please explain a reason why this is happening? It seems whatever catch block is in the top is being caught first.

I don't think this is the correct behavior and that the string exception block should be executed, but if I am wrong, please correct me. Thanks for taking time to look at this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void MightGoWrong()
{
    bool error = true;
    if (error)
    {
        throw string("Something else went wrong");
    }
}

/**
 * Output on console: Int exception occurred: 14947880
 */
int main() {
    try
    {
        MightGoWrong();
    }
    // If string or char pointer catch block goes to top, that block will execute
    catch (int e)  
    {
        cout << "Int exception occurred: " << e << endl;
    }
    catch (string &e)
    {
        cout << "String exception occurred: " << e << endl;
    }
    catch (char const * e)
    {
        cout << "Char exception occurred: " << e << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/FWUnsq) with gcc - what compiler are you using ?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/rzkAaG).

Comment: Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/804ac69f8bab9bf9) with gcc/clang.

Comment: I am using GCC v 5.3.0. Hmmm i see. There must be something up with my compiler

Comment: Or you are not running the code you posted...

Comment: I tried cleaning and rebuilding multiple times but i am still getting the same results

Comment: try throwing a float and have a float catch block right on top. What happens?

Comment: What about if you add `#include <string>`?

Comment: @Prab I tried throwing a float error with the float catch block on the top and it is going to the float catch block.
Once i move the float catch block below the int block, it is then going to the int catch block.

Comment: @AntoJurković I just tried adding the include string preprocessor statement, and the result is still the same. Still executing the first catch block no matter what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to use #include <string> beside <iostream>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506095/do-i-have-to-use-include-string-beside-iostream)

Comment: @J.Lee that should not happen. Whether you have the float catch block after or before the int catch block control will flow to the float catch block if you throw a float exception. There's definitely something amiss with your environment. btw I asked you to try the float case just to prove that it's not just the string case which is not working

Comment: @prab. Thank you for the clarification. I was guessing that something was wrong with my environment. I guess i ll start taking a look at my compiler settings. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I just tried running the same code using the Visual C++ compiler (as opposed to my GCC) and its working as expected. There is definitely something funky with the GCC settings on my localhost. Thank you everybody for the help!