# How to access c++ string by index for a integer number?

Tags: c++

How do i edit this program for j to contain "1"?

Currently it shows 49 which is the ascii value i think.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
  string i = "123";
  int j = i[0];
  cout << j;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, for starters, you include [`<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) , which is the contracted mandate for bringing `std::string` to your C++ party. If it "works" without it, it is by chance; not design, and engineers don't like coding by chance.

Comment: just subtract `'0'` from `j`

Comment: @WhozCraig According to the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506109, `std::string` must be fully defined even if you have only included `<iostream>`. However, I agree you should still include `<string>` so you don’t accidentally calls non-member functions that are only defined in `<string>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as shown below:

```
int main()
{
  std::string i = "123";
  int j = i[0] - '0'; //this is the important statement
  std::cout << j;
}
```

##### Explanation

`'0'` is a [**character literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

So when i wrote:

```
int j = i[0] - '0';
```

The **fundamental reason** why/how `i[0] - '0'` works is through [**promotion**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).
In particular,

> both `i[0]` and `'0'` will be **promoted to `int`**. And the final result that is used to **initialize** variable `j` on the left hand side will be the resultant of **subtraction** of those two **promoted** `int` values on the right hand side.

And the result is **guaranteed** by the Standard C++ to be the integer `1` since from [**C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.charset)

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>    each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>    one greater than the value of the previous.

So there is **no need** to use magic number like `48` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subtract ASCII '0' (48) from the character digit:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string i = "123";
  int j = i[0] - 48;  // ASCII for '0' is 48
  // or
  // int j = i[0] - '0';
  cout << j;
}
```

Comment: The character `'0'` is the correct character digit for *any* encoding, not only ASCII. Using the magic number `48` would be forcing ASCII while `'0'` is portable to any C++ implementation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, didn't knew this. Thanks will make the edits.

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct a new string from character.
2. Convert the substring to integer.
   Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
  string i = "123";

  // Method 1, use constructor
  string s1(1, i[0]);
  cout << s1 << endl;

  // Method 2, use convertor
  int j = atoi(s1.c_str());
  cout << j << endl;
}
```

Comment: Method 2 is much better but the question was about getting only first digit not the entire number.

Comment: @AshutoshRaghuwanshi
Both methods get the same result. I have tested them before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple , just cast **j** to char .
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
  string i = "123";
  int j = i[0];
  cout << char(j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `j` to be a `char` instead of an `int`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string i = "123";
  char j = i[0];
  cout << j;
}
```